# Use pandas df.concat to replace .append with custom index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm currently trying to replace .append in my code since it won't be supported in the future and I have some trouble with the custom index I'm using
I read the names of every .shp files in a directory and extract some date from it
To make the link with an excel file I have, I use the name I extract from the title of the file

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['date','fichier'])
    for i in glob.glob("*.shp"):
        nom_parcelle = i.split("_")[2]
        if not nom_parcelle in df.index:
            # print(df.last_valid_index())
            date_recolte = i.split("_")[-1]
            new_row = pd.Series(data={'date':date_recolte.split(".")[0], 'fichier':i}, name = nom_parcelle)
            df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=False)
```

This works exactly as I want it to be
Sadly, I can't find a way to replace it with .concat

I looked for ways to keep the index whith concat but didn't find anything that worked as I intended
Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try the approach below with [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) based on your code :

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
​
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['date','fichier'])
dico_dfs={}
​
for i in glob.glob("*.shp"):
    nom_parcelle = i.split("_")[2]
    if not nom_parcelle in df.index:
        # print(df.last_valid_index())
        date_recolte = i.split("_")[-1]
        new_row = pd.Series(data={'date':date_recolte.split(".")[0], 'fichier':i}, name = nom_parcelle)
        dico_dfs[i]= new_row.to_frame()
        
df= pd.concat(dico_dfs, ignore_index=False, axis=1).T.droplevel(0)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)
           date                  fichier
nom1   20220101   a_xx_nom1_20220101.shp
nom2   20220102   b_yy_nom2_20220102.shp
nom3   20220103   c_zz_nom3_20220103.shp
```

Comment: That worked exactly as intended, thanks
But I'm having a new problem now 
'''if dataframe.loc[i]['Ratoon'] == 0:'''
Was working with .append but now i get this error 
''' ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'''
What could it be?